# asp.net Do not validate Modal form when hidden

Tags: asp.net, validation, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal form (bootstrap), I am using asp.net RequiredFieldValidtors for data entry validation. This validation **should only fire when the modal is visible** and the user is entering new values into the modal.

The problem I am having is that the validation triggers when the model form is not shown preventing my main page from accepting new data entry from. My modal is only used to add new values and is not part of the normal workflow on my main page.

I have been stuck on this for two days now and have tried many different things and just can't get it figured out.

Any suggestions on how to handle this while keeping my RequiredFieldValidator rules intact?

Thanks

Edit - Adding modal forms code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal fade" id="modNewStakeholder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stakeholder</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control focus" ID="tFirstName" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" placeholder="First name is required"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rftFirstName"
                                runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required Field"
                                ControlToValidate="tFirstName" Display="Dynamic"
                                ValidationGroup="ValGroupNewStake"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Last Name:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="tLastName" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" placeholder="Last name is required"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rftLastName"
                               runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required Field" ControlToValidate="tLastName" Display="Dynamic"
                               ValidationGroup="ValGroupNewStake"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">E-Mail:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="tEmail" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" placeholder="Email must contain @expeditors.com"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rftEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tEmail" Display="Dynamic"
                                ValidationGroup="ValGroupNewStake"
                                ErrorMessage="Required Field">
                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rftEmailAt" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tEmail" Display="Dynamic"
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid Email, must contain @"
                                ValidationGroup="ValGroupNewStake"
                                ValidationExpression="^\w+[\w-\.]*\@\w+((-\w+)|(\w*))\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rftEmailDomaain" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tEmail" Display="Dynamic"
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid Email, must be an @abc.com domain"
                                ValidationGroup="ValGroupNewStake"
                                ValidationExpression="^.+@[Aa][Bb][Cc][.][Cc][Oo][Mm]$">
                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="cmdOk_AddSholder" runat="server" onserverclick="cmdOk_AddSholder_ServerClick" ValidationGroup="ValGroupNewStake" causesvalidation="false">Ok</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="cmdCancel_AddSholder" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" onserverclick="cmdCancel_AddSholder_ServerClick">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdOk_AddSholder" EventName="serverclick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Does your code attempt to enable/disable the RequiredFieldValidator in the same are where the Modal is made visible/invisible? I would have it disabled on the source page by default. Actually, the first thing I would try is setting the ValidationGroup for any validators in that modal.

Comment: We'll need to see your source and code behind to help you better.

Comment: Tony, I have tried the following: First, had no update panel, then added the panel hoping it would isolate the modal. I then tried adding a validation group hoping that the group would validate only when the button was clicked. I also am doing some things in code behind to set fake values in the fields to prevent them from failing. I have come to the conclusion that the things I am doing is just making things worse. Just need to understand a good approach on how to handle. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain a very simplified user control with validation that can be used as a modal.

Comment: Thanks Tony, this makes sense. I am trying this out right now. It appears that I have some other issues as I have two modals on the same page, trying to untangle it all now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a very simplified example of how my application is doing this. The Modal is just an ascx control and does **not** have an `updatepanel`. It's actually just a control becoming visible but we use CSS and JavaScript to make it a modal. The same logic should still apply as I've made this sample from a functioning modal.

**Modal.ascx**

Validators have ValidationGroup and are disabled. Button is also assigned to ValidationGroup:

```
<div id="approvalModal" style="display: none;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Enabled="false"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="testValidationgGroup" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="testValidationgGroup" />
</div>
```

**Modal.ascx.vb**

Enable the validator in a property:

```
Partial Class Modal
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public WriteOnly Property Enable() As Boolean
        Set(value As Boolean)
            RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**PageWithModal.aspx** (note: uses jQuery)

```
<script>
    function setupTestModal() {
        var modal = $('#approvalModal');
        if (modal.css('display') == 'none') {
            modal.show();
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="ShowModal" runat="server" Text="Show Modal" OnClick="ShowModal_Click" />
<uc1:Modal runat="server" ID="testModal" />
```

**PageWithModal.aspx.vb**

Notice that when you click the ShowModal button, the validation does NOT fire. However, when the modal is visible, the Validator has been enabled.

```
Protected Sub ShowModal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    testModal.Enable = True
    Dim script = String.Concat("setupTestModal();")
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType(), "Popup", script, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a million Tony. I untangled my mess and the implemented the enabled methods to control the validators from code behind, working like it should now. Much appreciated.